# C# DropDownList cant get value from CellClick DataGrid

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, datagrid

I have a datagrid in C#.
In my windows a single Combobox with DropDownList.
But when i try to get the value in the datagrid with CellClick the value dont change.
With DropDown works fine, but for my project i need DropDownList.
I create a label to check if this label change.
The label change but not the combobox.
What is wrong ?

```
private void CaballerosDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        int index = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = CaballerosDataGridView.Rows[index];
        CaballerosDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        NombreCaballerosTextBox.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        string cat = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        CategoriaCaballerosComboBox.Text = cat;
        ////string item = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ////CategoriaCaballerosComboBox.SelectedValue = item;
        ////CategoriaCaballerosComboBox.Text = item;
        ////string item = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ////CategoriaCaballerosComboBox.SelectedValue = CaballerosDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value
        CaballerosDataGridView.Columns[3].Visible = true;
        string mypic = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        CaballeroPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(mypic);

        label3.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;




    }
```

Thanks for help....

Comment: What is `DropDownList` and `DropDown` ? What `ColumnType` is the column when the app works vs doesnt work?

Comment: [link](https://postimg.cc/p92R4DSN)
This is DropDown & DropDownList
Works with DropDown // Doesnt work with DropDownList

Comment: Im confused, are you working on a  `DataGridView` or just a regulat `ComboBox` ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok i find

CategoriaCaballerosComboBox.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim();